# how to i get the total number of letters for each word

Tags: python

im trying to create a program that counts the number of letters in each word that is entered. I also want the program to print the one with the highest amount of letters and the word it corresponds with. I dont know how to count the number of letters in each word

this is my code so far. how do i get the number of letters?

```
names = {}

nametest = True
while nametest:
  
  name = input("Enter a name. Enter E to end. ")
  count = name.index(name)
  names[name] =count
  
  
  if name == 'E':
    print("You have entered", names.values())
 
    highest = max(zip(names.keys(), names.values()), key=lambda t : t[1])[0]
    
    print("Longest name was:",highest.upper(), "with", max(names.values()), "letters")

    break
```

Comment: replace `count = name.index(name)` by `count = len(name)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit your code just a little bit to make it work

```
names = {}

while True:
    name = input("Enter a name. Enter E to end: ")
    if name == 'E':
        break
    count = len(name)
    names[name] = count

print("You have entered these names and this is their letter count:")
for name, count in names.items():
    print(f"{name}: {count} letters")

longest_name = max(names, key=lambda x: names[x])
longest_count = names[longest_name]

print("Longest name was:", longest_name.upper(), "with", longest_count, "letters")
```